# How to set a image over another in the same <img> tag via CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-image, image

I have the strict need to set a big background under a little button icon in such a way:

```
<img 
src="little-icon.png"
style="background: url('main-image.jpg') no-repeat center; 
margin: auto; padding: 0; 
height: 240px; width: 180px;" 
/>
```

Where height and width are the parameters of the (big) main background image. In a nutshell: I need to set img.src as a clickable icon, and its background-image as a big image. This is something quite simple to do with a div tag which wraps the img one. But I have, due to other circumstances, to do all in the same img tag.

The code right above does its job, but the icon is deformed to the size of the background one. Is there the chance to do what I need to do?

Comment: Why can you use just one img tag?

Comment: using  css so many easy way to do this,so better change your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are better ways to do this, but if you absolutely have to do it your way, use padding - setting the width and height of your image with CSS, will definitely deform it ...

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/yp3Wx/) (using :hover as way of explanation)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you can do that inside of one img tag, as the background and the image itself are assigned the same height and width so they will always overlap each other and be stretchd or shrunk into the dimensions you specify.
What you could do is merge the images into one, thats probably your only chance in case you are really stuck with a one tag only policy.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, when you apply height and width style to img tag, it will apply to the main image ie image in src. You can only control the background position within that area.

As per the question, if you want large background below, small icon, you need to create the large image of icon with transparent background.